# Next Start - too slow and images do not load with Next/Image

Tags: next.js

I believe I followed every single step mentioned in the documentation but can't seem to get images load with 'next start' script.

1. Next.config.js

```
images: {
    domains: [
      'dev.mydomain.com',
      'qa.mydomain.com',
      'stg.mydomain.com',
      'mydomain.com',
    ],
  },
```

2. I have images in public/assets/images directory. These are .png files
3. In my React component that is used on one of the pages, I have

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import homeIntroImg from '../../../public/assets/images/homeIntro.png';
 .....
 <Image
           src={homeIntroImg}
           alt="Home Introduction"
           placeholder="blur"
 />
```

4. As mentioned in docs, I have installed 'sharp' and added environment variable. /usr/src/app is the working directory path in docker.

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "NEXT_SHARP_PATH=/usr/src/app/node_modules/sharp next start ",
```

5. Dockerfile

```
FROM base-image-node-16.0:latest AS runner
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

USER 2020

COPY --chown=2020:2020 . /usr/src/app 

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

On local when i try to build docker container,
I get

```
Warning: For production Image Optimization with Next.js, the optional 'sharp' package is strongly recommended. Run 'yarn add sharp', and Next.js will use it automatically for Image Optimization.
```

but images load fine.

When the same docker image is deployed to cluster, the initial load time is almost 10-15 sec. This wasn't happening like this when I run the app using 'node server.js'. I wanted to use 'next start' as recommended to get optimization benefits but now I question if it is worth to use 'next start' if it takes 10-15 sec for load.
images do not load and fail with 503 service unavailable error.
I see the 'Sharp' warning and right after that 'npm' crashes

```
Warning: For production Image Optimization with Next.js, the optional 'sharp' package is strongly recommended. Run 'yarn add sharp', and Next.js will use it automatically for Image Optimization.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production
Killed
```

Am I missing anything? Any help is greatly appreciated.